# Issue with Excel VBA crashing constantly

Tags: vba, excel

I'm building a sheet that will change depending on some selections. I have ranges defined that will be used to copy and paste the different data depending on what kind of sheet should get displayed to the user.

Since I built the copy and pasting mechanism, the sheet has been crashing a lot when I run the code to swap the sheet to look differently.

I get "Method 'PasteSpecial' of object 'Range' failed" on my error check and then "Run-time error "-2147417848 (80010108)': Automation error The object invoked has disconnected from its clients." that randomly will occur, sometimes the sheet runs fantastic with no errors and othertimes it is swamped with errors. Usually after this error comes up, I will hit end, and then I'll get a "Microsoft Excel has stopped working" error "windows can try to restart the program".  It sometimes recovers but normally not.

**I have attempted to copy the cells and paste them without any macros or code and excel has been crashing.** I am copy and pasting a bunch of formatted borders and background colours as well as some text that are in the boxes as well.

```
Public Sub SetupSheetForEquipmentType(equipment As EquipType)
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Input")


Dim info As Worksheet
Set info = Sheets("Info")


Call Unprotect(ws)

ws.Range("selectedEquipType") = equipment

'Normarc Style
'show all rows first
On Error Resume Next
If ws.Rows(14).EntireRow.Hidden = True Then
    ws.Rows(14).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    ws.Rows(16).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    ws.Columns(2).EntireColumn.Hidden = False
End If
On Error GoTo errSec
'setup the sheet
'Application.DisplayAlerts = False
'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Select Case equipment
Case Is = 2
    ws.Range("title") = "ILS PHL7801 MONITOR READINGS"
Case Is = 3
    ws.Range("title") = "ILS NORMARC 'A' MONITOR READINGS"
Case Is = 4
    ws.Range("title") = "ILS NORMARC 'B' MONITOR READINGS"
End Select

If Not equipment = PHL7801 Then

    ws.Rows(24).RowHeight = 15
    ws.Rows(25).RowHeight = 15
    ws.Columns(3).ColumnWidth = 6

    'make the sheet input look appropriate
    info.Range("NMSheet").Copy
    DoEvents
    DoEvents
    DoEvents
    ws.Range("SheetGuts").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll '************crashes here*********** but works with xlPasteValues

    'put the comment box in
    info.Range("NMComment").Copy
    ws.Range("NMCommentRef").PasteSpecial 
    ThisWorkbook.Names("comment").Delete
    ws.Range("I35").Name = "comment"
End If

Select Case equipment
Case Is = NMA

    info.Range("NMACL").Copy
    DoEvents
    DoEvents
    DoEvents
    DoEvents
    ws.Range("NMCPNames").PasteSpecial xlPasteAllExceptBorders, xlPasteSpecialOperationNone

    info.Range("NMADS").Copy
    DoEvents
    DoEvents
    DoEvents
    DoEvents
    ws.Range("NMDSNames").PasteSpecial xlPasteAllExceptBorders, xlPasteSpecialOperationNone

    info.Range("NMARef").Copy
    DoEvents
    DoEvents
    DoEvents
    DoEvents
    ws.Range("NMRefNames").PasteSpecial xlPasteAllExceptBorders, xlPasteSpecialOperationNone

Case Is = NMB
    info.Range("NMBCL").Copy
    DoEvents
    DoEvents
    DoEvents
    DoEvents
    ws.Range("NMCPNames").PasteSpecial xlPasteAllExceptBorders, xlPasteSpecialOperationNone

    info.Range("NMBDS").Copy
    DoEvents
    DoEvents
    DoEvents
    DoEvents
    ws.Range("NMDSNames").PasteSpecial xlPasteAllExceptBorders, xlPasteSpecialOperationNone

    info.Range("NMBRef").Copy
    DoEvents
    DoEvents
    DoEvents
    DoEvents
    ws.Range("NMRefNames").PasteSpecial xlPasteAllExceptBorders, xlPasteSpecialOperationNone

Case Is = PHL7801

    'make the sheet input look appropriate
    info.Range("PHLSheet").Copy
    DoEvents
    DoEvents
    DoEvents
    ws.Range("SheetGuts").PasteSpecial

    'hide the rows that aren't applicable and size them appropriately
    ws.Columns(2).Hidden = True
    ws.Rows(14).Hidden = True
    ws.Rows(16).Hidden = True
    ws.Rows(24).RowHeight = 30
    ws.Rows(25).RowHeight = 30
    ws.Columns(3).ColumnWidth = 10

    info.Range("PHLCL").Copy
    DoEvents
    DoEvents
    DoEvents
    DoEvents
    DoEvents
    ws.Range("NMCPNames").PasteSpecial xlPasteAllExceptBorders, xlPasteSpecialOperationNone

    info.Range("PHLDS").Copy
    DoEvents
    DoEvents
    DoEvents
    DoEvents
    ws.Range("NMDSNames").PasteSpecial xlPasteAllExceptBorders, xlPasteSpecialOperationNone

    info.Range("PHLRef").Copy
    DoEvents
    DoEvents
    DoEvents
    DoEvents
    DoEvents
    ws.Range("NMRefNames").PasteSpecial xlPasteAllExceptBorders, xlPasteSpecialOperationNone

    'put the comment box in
    info.Range("PHLComment").Copy
    DoEvents
    DoEvents
    DoEvents
    DoEvents
    DoEvents
    ws.Range("NMCommentRef").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll, xlPasteSpecialOperationNone

    ThisWorkbook.Names("comment").Delete
    ws.Range("D35").Name = "comment"
End Select
errSec:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then

    MsgBox "Error: " & Err.Description
    Err.Clear
End If

Call Protect(ws)
'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
'Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Edit: 
I also have been reading and determined that dumping the temporary files is supposed to help, located here: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp. Between that and Charles's answer, it seems to be working okay, except I'm getting an error on my catch saying: "To do this, all the merged cells need to be the same size". I am wondering if there is an issue with all the merged cells I have?

Edit Again: I spoke too soon. I noticed that the copy and paste was not working correctly by using the xlpastevalues, so I changed it to xlPasteAll and its now crashing again.

Comment: Merged cells are the devil's work, just FYI. You can't paste in to a range containing merged cells unless you're pasting identially merged cells, if I recall correctly. Also, the fact that you're quadrupling calls to `DoEvents` suggests that there are some other problems that need to also be optimized.

Comment: Why don't you just create several different sheets, each formatted/merged etc as needed, and then simply Hide/Unhide as they need to be displayed to the users?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Trying to save myself a bunch of code because I'm also taking the values from the cells and putting them into a class to copy them to another sheet. That and my sheet has a bunch of buttons at the top of it. The DoEvents seemed to fix these crashes earlier, but they came back.

Comment: So there is definitely some differently merged cells that I'm trying to copy over. I think I may have to go your hide/unhide if this is whats getting excel so cranky at me. Just a lot of extra work.

Comment: No, you can just unmerge them, then do the copy. See my suggestion in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your missing the paste values

```
ws.Range("SheetGuts").PasteSpecial xPasteValues
```

Comment: so added this in, and stepped through the code and noticed a new error on my catch, it now says "To do this, all the merged cells need to be the same size". The copy and paste worked fine though, however. Excel is no longer crashing, but any idea how to fix this error catch thats happening? I've basically changed the error catch to resume next and the program is now working, I am just worried it will start doing the same thing again intermittently.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `.Copy` and then `.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll` (and also avoiding the repetitive `DoEvents`, can you see if this works:

```
ws.Range("NMRefNames").Unmerge
info.Range("NMSheet").Copy Destination:=ws.Range("NMRefNames")
```

You may also need to do similar on the next block:

```
info.Range("NMComment").Copy
ws.Range("NMCommentRef").PasteSpecial
```

If there are or may be merged cells:

```
info.Range("NMComment").Copy Destination:=ws.Range("NMCommentRef")
ws.Range("NMCommentRef").Value = ws.Range("NMCommentRef").Value  'Gets rid of formula/etc
```

Also, for your PasteAllExceptBorders blocks, try doing this on all of them:

```
info.Range("NMBDS").Copy Destination:=ws.Range("NMDSNames")
ws.Range("NMDSNames").Borders.LineStyle = xlNone
```

Comment: So when I try to unmerge, it is now crashing. Even if I am not using VBA, I just grab some cells and press unmerge on the ribbon at the top, it crashes instantly. To be specific, excel will crash if I try to unmerge 5 or more cells. 4 or less unmerges fine.

Comment: Do you have any worksheet event handlers that may be triggering some sort of infinite loop?

Comment: If so, you need to address those. If not, shut down excel completely and see if the problem persists if you open a brand new/empty workbook and try to merge/unmerge cells. If no problem, then re-open your file and see if it happens. If it does, reboot and try again. Sounds stupid, but sometimes that is all it takes.

Comment: So I do have some formula's in one of the cells I'm unmerging. It doesn't seem to like unmerging the formula'd cells. 

No worksheet event handlers. I've tried repairing excel and restoring, it doesn't appear to happen on a new workbook.

Comment: Since I'm clueless on why this stuff is happening, I'll just say that I have been goofing around with using the copy command only, no pastespecial and now I've gotten the following error code: "There isn't enough memory to complete this action. Try using less data or closing other applications. To increase memory availability, consider: using a 64-bit version of excel, adding memory to your device"

Comment: Did you do either of the things I last suggested? And does your worksheet(s) have event code that might be triggering infinite loops? Please answer before you go off on some other tangent... I'll check back tomorrow.

Comment: Also, how big are these ranges you're talking about? Are they like, 30 rows, or 300,000 rows? The `Copy` command is very resource-intensive especially on large ranges of data, and this can usually be avoided by periodic `Save` of the workbook, but I can't say for sure.

Comment: I'm pretty convinced that this is completely an issue with the ability for Excel to handle working with merged cells and copy-pasting. It's about 30 rows or so. I've shut down and restarted excel numerous times (as the program crashes all the time) I've tried rebooting as well which doesn't seem to make a difference. For future reference of other people that may have stumbled on this, if you are working with merged cells and copy and paste, bad things happen. I'm going to try and build the program differently I don't think there is a reasonable solution here. Thanks for the help, David.